# Aurelia. Why is my nested repeat.for select not displaying data?

Tags: nested, aurelia

I have the below simple table displaying users and their roles. My nested repeat.for loops through a list of roles. My repeat.for="role of rolesData" does not display my data. Can you tell me why not? It only works if I add the 3rd repeat.for inside the div tag.

```
    <tbody>
     <tr repeat.for="user of usersData">
     <td>${user.name}</td>
     <td>
      <select>
       <option repeat.for="role of rolesData">${role.name}</option>
      </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
      <div repeat.for="role of rolesData">
   <tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's difficult to answer without seeing you `js/ts` but I'm pretty sure what causing your problem.

I'm guessing you have a `rolesData` property in your VM that is being populated in an AJAX call.
this means that when the page first loads, `rolesData` is still not defined.
and then, in the `then` of the ajax call, you probably do `this.rolesData = data` or something similar.
note that even if you declare a property called `rolesData` in your class, it will have no affect until you are actually assign something to it (even assigning `undefined` is good).

in aurelia - when you bind to an un-existing property, aurelia will create it for you and bind to it.
therefor you never have exceptions or something similar.

in your case, you are binding to an un-existing property inside a `repeat` loop.
in the repeat, each repetition create a local scope for the current variable,
binding to an un-existing property inside of a child scope create a new property in the child scope.
therefor, even when in a later time - you actually populate `rolesData` with stuff, its being populated in the parent scope - but each child is bounded to a different collection (each child have it's own scope).

when you have the external `div` bounded to the same variable, you have a little side-effect that is causing the whole thing to work.
because the external `div` creates a variable in the parent scope, and now each child - instead of creating a local variable in their respected scopes - they will use the same variable that already exists in the parent scope.
and then - later when you populate the same variable - the binding keeks in and every thing look nice.

TL;DR:
in your VM, declare `rolesData = undefined`; instead of just declaring it.